# How to redirect a button to root url in flask?

Tags: python-3.x, web, flask

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("webpage.html")
```

I have the above function in my flaskPage.py file and I want to make a link from the Back to Home button shown below to the above root url. However, url_for doesn't accept empty string as an argument and throws an error as follows

```
<button formaction="{{ url_for('') }}">Back to Home</button>
```

Error

```
Could not build url for endpoint ''
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form method="get" action="{{url_for('index')}}">
<button> Back to Home </button>
</form>
```

This solved it.

Comment: I feel like this should be unnecessary. It would help a lot of people to just autocorrect `''` and `'/'` to `'index'`

Comment: I had to use `'homehandler'`