# How to redirect root url in Flask

Tags: python, flask, url, redirect, root

I am trying to do speech synthesis web page using Flask. When i synthesis speech it goes another url. With a button i should be return to the root url(home page). I tried [How to redirect a button to root url in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60672646/how-to-redirect-a-button-to-root-url-in-flask) this topic but it doesnt make root url, makes it after host "/?".

**Flask code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import inference

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/sentez", methods = ["POST"])
def sentez():
    if request.method == "POST":
        metin = request.form["metin"]
        created_audio = inference.create_model(metin)
    return render_template("index.html", my_audio = created_audio)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run();
```

**Html code**

```
{% if not my_audio %}
    <form action="{{ url_for("sentez") }}" method="POST">   
        <textarea id="textalaniid" class="textalani" name="metin"></textarea>
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Seslendir</button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
{% if my_audio %}
    <form action="{{ url_for("home") }}" method="GET">  
        <textarea class="textalani"></textarea>
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Ana Sayfaya Dön</button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I think you should use single quotation inside double quotation, what are you doing in myFunction

Comment: Double quotation works for "sentez" url. myfunction is for if textarea empty but its unable for second form.

Comment: What do you mean by make it after host "/?".

Comment: When i click second form button, i want to return http://127.0.0.1:5000/ but it returns http://127.0.0.1:5000/?

Comment: This is because you are using forget request, this should not create any problem. Is it creating?

Comment: Sometimes it doesnt return created audio, returns previous created sound. Idk may be it happens because of "/?".

Comment: Are you doing something in index function or only returning index.html

Comment: Only returning index.html.

Comment: try writing this `return render_template("index.html", my_audio = created_audio)`  in if scope and outside the scope return something which you want users to view before they submit their form.

Comment: How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

What about using:

```
return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

instead of

```
return render_template("index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def sentez():
    if request.method == "POST":
        metin = request.form["metin"]
        created_audio = inference.create_model(metin)
        return render_template("index.html", my_audio = created_audio)
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: It didnt change the url question mark thing.

Comment: does it solve the problem of returning previous audio.

Comment: it will not solve that and that's not an issue see in the url of this page. do you see `?noredirect=.. ` this is because of get request.

Comment: No still it returns previous audio sometimes. I agree with you url thing is not the problem. Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Can you give the whole code so that I can run and see what is the problem.